# How to remove words with digits without removing a digit at the beginning of a string?

Tags: perl, unix

I'm doing some tweet sentiment analysis, and right now I'm trying to clean the data using perl on Ubuntu command line.
I have some data in the follow format:

```
sentiment, 'text'
```

Where `sentiment = {0, 4}` and `text is any valid string`.
Right now I'm having trouble removing data such as this:

```
0,'My 21yo son has finally graduated from college!'
4,'The NT2000 is an awesome product!'
4,'what is good88guy doing on my following list?'
```

I want the following to look like this after:

```
0,'My son has finally graduated from college!'
4,'The is an awesome product!'
4,'what is doing on my following list?'
```

I don't want to remove the sentiment and I also need to remove the `yo`. Any ideas how I can write this script?

Comment: Try to force some word to come after the "at least 1" digit, like `'s/\d{1,}\w\{1,}//g'`.

Comment: I can't believe that `s/\d*//g` would transform `21yo` into ``.

Comment: Sorry about that. I fixed up my question.

Comment: @dtgee I've updated my answer, try it out.

Comment: Please explain what you mea by *"and not at the beginning?"*

Comment: Reedited my question title. Sorry for being unclear. Not sure if the title makes more sense now. Maybe you have a better suggestion for a title?

Comment: @dtgee: Ah! So you are showing the contents of a file, and `0,'My 21yo son has finally graduated from college!'` is a single line from the file. I apologise: I imagined that you were showing the contents of a Perl data stucture. It is unusual to see strings delimited by single quotes in CSV files and it changes the question. The first step is to use [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/module/Text::CSV) to read your file before you start to change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try this:

```
s/ ?( |[a-z]+)\d+( |[a-z]+|)? ?/ /simg;
```

***DEMO***
http://regex101.com/r/zW2nJ3

Comment: Not sure if you saw my edit, but your regex removes the digit, but not also the words that contain the digits.

Comment: There are no dots `.`, dollars `$` or carets `^` in your regex, so the `/s` and `/m` modifiers are irrelevant

Comment: @Borodin point taken, but they may exist with different examples.

Comment: @Tuga: I don't buy that, so -1 My biggest worry about your solution is that it has been tuned very precisely to a specific interpretation of the problem. If the OP needs to modify his definition of *words that should be excluded* then it will be a struggle for him. Adding `/sm` to an already-complex regex is just confusing

Comment: @dtgee: Do you *understand* what this solution does and how it works?

Comment: @Tuga: I am pretty sure that not even you can guarantee what your regex does. *"An optional space, followed by a capture that may be a space or several letters..."* and already it seems unstructured. You have retained irrelevant `/m` and `/s` modifiers and you have two purposeless captures. It looks very much like you have tinkered with your pattern until it performs properly on the sample data set. That is not the right way to create software, and I have no confidence at all that your answer will perform as required

Comment: @Borodin I'm having a rough day... just take it easy, regards.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want the following:

```
s/\w*\d\w*\s*//g;
```

You're statement that you don't want things removed "from the beginning" is a little confusing, but you'll have to add more information to get a better answer.

One of the easiest methods to communicate what you want is to create a list of before and after strings, trying to make each demonstrate an special case.

Comment: You're completely right. I should have just put before and after results. Thanks for helping me to clarify my question.

Comment: Also I just tried your script. I got the following: , 
`,'My  son has finally graduated from college!'`
`,'The  is an awesome product!'`
`,'what is  doing on my following list?'`

Comment: I've updated my regex to handle spacing like you've now specified in your updated post.

Answer (score 0):

Since your recent comments I have understood your problem a little better.

The data format you describe *must* be processed using [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aCSV), so as to account for quoted fields and comma separators.

This program should suit your needs as far as I understand them. It has `use autodie` to avoid the need for hand-coding exceptions if the input file cannot be opened, and `Text::CSV` reads the data from the file, specifying single quotes as field delimiters.

I have used the code from my original answer to process each line of the file, as it provides the best flexibility if your requirements need to be refined.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use Text::CSV;

my $csv_proc = Text::CSV->new({ eol => $/, quote_char => "'" });

open my $fh, '<', 'myfile.txt';

while ( my $row = $csv_proc->getline($fh) ) {
  my @fields = split ' ', $row->[1];
  $row->[1] = join ' ', grep { not /\d/ } @fields;
  $csv_proc->print(*STDOUT, $row);
}
```

**output**

```
0,'My son has finally graduated from college!'
4,'The is an awesome product!'
4,'what is doing on my following list?'
```